# Asp.net, Response.Redirect not working. Why?

Tags: asp.net

In my application, I'm trying to redirect to another page after a record is inserted into my datasource. The insert part works fine, but the page never redirects. Any ideas? Here's my current code:

**ASPX**

```
   <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RecapID" 
    DataSourceID="RecapDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            Recap Date:
            <asp:TextBox ID="RecapDateTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("RecapDate") %>' Width="80px" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="RecapDateTextBox" ErrorMessage="*" display="Dynamic" />
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Create"/>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="RecapDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"  
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ftsrms_Recap] ([RecapDate]) VALUES (@RecapDate) SELECT @NewRecapID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="RecapDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewRecapID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**ASPX.VB**

```
Protected Sub RecapDataSource_Inserted(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)

    'Read the value of the @NewProductID OUTPUT parameter
    Dim newRecapID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewRecapID").Value)

    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?")

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that RecapDataSource_Inserted handles the Inserted event?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint on that line and see if it actually get hit. If not, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event handler to *RecapDataSource*:

**oninserted="RecapDataSource_Inserted"**

So your aspx code becomes:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RecapID" 
    DataSourceID="RecapDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            Recap Date:
            <asp:TextBox ID="RecapDateTextBox" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Bind("RecapDate") %>' Width="80px" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="RecapDateTextBox" ErrorMessage="*" display="Dynamic" />
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                CommandName="Insert" Text="Create"/>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="RecapDataSource" runat="server"
    oninserted="RecapDataSource_Inserted"
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"  
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [ftsrms_Recap] ([RecapDate]) VALUES (@RecapDate) SELECT @NewRecapID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="RecapDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="NewRecapID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Edit:**

Also Change this:

```
Protected Sub RecapDataSource_Inserted(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)

    'Read the value of the @NewProductID OUTPUT parameter
    Dim newRecapID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewRecapID").Value)

    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?")

End Sub
```

to this:

```
Protected Sub RecapDataSource_Inserted(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

    'Read the value of the @NewProductID OUTPUT parameter
    Dim newRecapID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewRecapID").Value)

    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx?")

End Sub
```

If it still does not works, remove this line (or comment) and try again:

```
Dim newRecapID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewRecapID").Value)
```

May be it rises exception.

Comment: Tried your suggestion Vano, but the debugger threw the following error: Error 1 Method 'Protected Sub RecapDataSource_Inserted(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub SqlDataSourceStatusEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)'.

Comment: None of the above worked, even commenting the line: Dim newRecapID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.Command.Parameters("@NewRecapID").Value).

Comment: Scratch the above, I resaved and recompiled with oninserted="RecapDataSource_Inserted" in the ASPX using the code behind with System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs and it worked. Thanks a bunch!